# Renaming all columns based on substring in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to rename columns in a dataframe using dplyr ...

```
SLX.16476.NEBNext01.H2CJLBBXY.s_6 <- c(5,4,4,2)
SLX.16476.NEBNext04.H2CJLBBXY.s_7 <- c(1,1,1,1)
SLX.16476.NEBNext04.H2CJLBBXY.s_8 <- c(8,3,4,9)
data <- data.frame(SLX.16476.NEBNext01.H2CJLBBXY.s_6, SLX.16476.NEBNext04.H2CJLBBXY.s_7, SLX.16476.NEBNext04.H2CJLBBXY.s_8)
```

I want colnames to be NEBNext01_6, NEBNext04_7, NEBNext04_8

Is there a way to do this easily in dplyr/tidyverse?

Comment: Use this to update the names of your dataset `names(data) = gsub("SLX.16476.|.H2CJLBBXY.s", "", names(data))`

Comment: thanks, how would you do it if SLX.16476 was not always the same or the H2CJ bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `?sub`

```
names(data) <- sub("^.*(NEBNext\\d+).*(_\\d+)$", "\\1\\2", names(data))
```

---

The name of the game is `regex`.

- have a look at `capturing groups` and how to "reference" them.

---

here is a version that is compatible with a pipe-chain.

```
data %>% {`names<-`(data, sub("^.*(NEBNext\\d+).*(_\\d+)$", "\\1\\2", names(.)))}
```

or as Sotos suggest to really dive into the tidyverse:

```
data %>% select_all(~sub("^.*(NEBNext\\d+).*(_\\d+)$", "\\1\\2",.))
```

or as zack suggests:

```
data %>% set_names(str_replace_all(names(.), "^.*(NEBNext\\d+).*(_\\d+)$", "\\1\\2"))
```

Comment: Thanks I was just hoping there was a tidyverse solution :)

Comment: Or even simpler, `data %>% select_all(~sub("^.*(NEBNext\\d+).*(_\\d+)$", "\\1\\2",.))`